# Geary doesn't use Gnome Contacts or history for email addresses

Tags: pantheon-mail

With [greetings from Fabby](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/missing-geary-contacts-suggestions/126234/3), I was referred to the elementary forums for this issue I am having with Geary.

Since Geary version 34.3, it [should make use of Gnome Contacts](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/09/geary-3-34-release-new-features) list. However, it doesn't show me any suggestions either from the contact list or from the history of used mail addresses.

I am using
Manjaro Gnome Stable.
Geary is 3.34.2 (tags/3.34.2-0-g5b5d6d94)
Gnome Contacts, version 3.34.1

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer myself. I swithed on Wayland in the Manjaro settings. Apparently (apart from some applications that stopped working) this functionality stopped functioning. I switched Wayland off and now everything works normal again.